# Select count multiple fields within time range - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with count multiple fields within time range.
I have following table:

```
# date, count, fb_user_count, email_user_count, reg_dt
'2015-10-27', '11', '6', '5', '2015-11-02 13:59:14'
'2015-10-26', '3', '1', '2', '2015-11-02 13:59:10'
```

I want to get weekly number of registration with types, like this:

```
# date, count, fb_user_count, email_user_count, reg_dt
'2015-11-02', '31', '16', '15', '2015-11-02 13:59:14'
'2015-11-09', '12', '6', '6', '2015-11-09 13:59:14'
```

And monthly:

```
# date, count, fb_user_count, email_user_count, reg_dt
'2015-11', '131', 'x', 'y', '2015-11-02 13:59:14' (the last value is not so important)
'2015-12', '112', 'x', 'y', '2015-12-09 13:59:14'
```

I tried different approaches, but I struggle to finish this task. Any help will be great. Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is a use-case for a calendar table, lots of good examples, here's one for mysql: https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables
You join to that on the date, then you can group by one of the other fields that equates a date to a given week/month.  You can usually do the same thing without a calender table, but it makes things easy, and provides a driver in cases where you want to return every week even if there were no results that week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MySQL Date and Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) `WEEK()`, `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` to build your queries :

```
SELECT
    MIN(date),
    SUM(count),
    SUM(fb_user_count),
    SUM(email_user_count)
FROM visit
GROUP BY WEEK(date, 1); -- First day is Monday

SELECT
    CONCAT(YEAR(date), '-', MONTH(date)),
    SUM(count),
    SUM(fb_user_count),
    SUM(email_user_count)
FROM visit
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your weekly report (on mondays) you can use

```
select subdate(min(date), 6-weekday(min(date))),
       sum(count), sum(fb_user_count), sum(email_user_count), max(reg_dt)
from tablename
group by subdate(date, 6-weekday(date));
```

and for your monthly report

```
select concat(year(max(date), '-', month(max(date)),
       sum(count), sum(fb_user_count), sum(email_user_count), max(reg_dt)
from tablename
group by year(date), month(date);
```